# Is the _PageStart different for every user?

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-webpages

I'm exploring the possibilities of the ASP.net Webpages 2 with Razor, and trying to make an application with Windows Authentication.

So I'd like to know if the _PageStart is executed for every user or just once and then cached? It is because I'd like to get some information from the database and store this information to be available trough the whole application. And how is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_PageStart.cshtml` is executed before each Razor template contrary to `_AppStart.cshtml` which is executed only once. You may take a look at the [following article](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/working-with-pages/18-customizing-site-wide-behavior) for a more detailed overview of those files.

Comment: Thnx.. I know the article, just read it briefly. So if both pages are executed only once, there it's not an option to store a session with the logonname or something like that..

Comment: You could store the currently connected username into the session when a user logs in. Then retrieve it from the session on each page that requires it.

Comment: Ok, but where can I do that when using Windows Authentication?